# Use old versions of JavaFX in Java 8

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-8, jnlp

I would like to use an old version of JavaFX in my web start application. It worked fine with Java 7 but now we got problems with Java 8. Is there any way to disable loading (in JNLP) of `jfxrt.jar`, which is on default classpath in Java 8? As I understand I can't use bootclasspath option in `java-vm-args` in JNLP in order to load old JavaFX jars before the default `jfxrt.jar` of Java 8. Is there any solutions or workarounds to this problem?

Thanks in advance.